# is it possible to logical AND two values from two different columns in COUNTIFS?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have the following formula:

`=COUNTIFS(Transactions2023[Result], "Win", Transactions2023[League], "NBA", Transactions2023[Date], "<=" & "4/11/2023")`

I actually need for all the values before or on 4/11/2023 at 5 PM to be counted, however I have the time listed in a separate column (`Transactions2023[Time]`). Is there a way for me to accomplish this in the formula? So I can AND the value from the date and time column together?

UPDATE: Per the kind folks below, have come up with:

`=COUNTIFS(Transactions2023[Result], "Win", Transactions2023[League], "NBA", Transactions2023[Date] + Transactions2023[Time], DATEVALUE(Transactions2023[Date]) + TIMEVALUE(Transactions2023[Time]) <= 45027 + (17/24))`

But I get the standard formula error. I've checked my ps and qs and everything seems to be fine, so wondering if I screwed up the syntax somewhere.

Comment: COUNTIFS is AND so just add: `Transactions2023[Time],"<=" & TIME(17,0,0)` to the countifs.

Comment: In general please always list/tag which version of Excel you're using, because not every formula/feature is available on every version.

Comment: combining the date and time should be with `+` (to add) so `Transactions2023[Date]+Transactions2023[Time]`. The criteria could be a something like `datevalue(...)+timevalue(...)`

Comment: @ScottCraner But won't that stop at the first instance of 5 PM even if it's not necessarily in the same row as 4/11/23?

Comment: @YisroelTech Done, it's Excel 365.

Comment: @gns100 I couldn't get this syntax to work.

Comment: `datevalue(...)+timevalue(...)`<= `45027 + (17/24)`

Comment: @SerPounce, as ScottCraner noted, COUNTIFS works like AND, it will only count if all the arguments match for the row.

Comment: To me it's a bit unclear what you're referencing, but this works fine for me: `=COUNTIFS(Transactions2023!A:A, "Win", Transactions2023!B:B, "NBA", Transactions2023!C:C,"<=" & "4/11/2023",Transactions2023!D:D,"<=" & TIME(17,0,0))`

Comment: @YisroelTech It doesn't give me the correct result because there are other rows that are not 4/11/2023 but are 5 PM or greater and it knocks those out.

Comment: @BlindSpots Thanks, can you explain that date format for me? Tried Googling and can't figure it out, is that somehow 4/11/2023?

Comment: Got you. The Excel serial date code is explained here https://exceljet.net/glossary/excel-date

Comment: @YisroelTech Cool appreciate it, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Had one last question, in the excel I'm using it's flagging an error on the three dots in datevalue(...). Is it supposed to be something else?

Comment: The reference to the range.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of your formula, the issue is at `Transactions2023[Date] + Transactions2023[Time], DATEVALUE(Transactions2023[Date]) + TIMEVALUE(Transactions2023[Time]) <= 45027 + (17/24)`

`DATEVALUE(Transactions2023[Date]) + TIMEVALUE(Transactions2023[Time])` isn't needed there.

There correct criteria:
`..., Transactions2023[Date] + Transactions2023[Time], "<=" & 45027 + (17/24))`

Comment: Thanks. I did try a simplified version "=COUNTIFS(Transactions2023[Result], "Win",  Transactions2023[Date] + Transactions2023[Time], "<=" & 45027 + (17/24))" and it still didn't work. I'm using Excel 365.

Comment: Please specify how exactly it doesn't work

Comment: It's giving the stock error message of a formula not working, but I see that it's also highlighting the left paranthesis in red in (17/24).

Comment: maybe you don't have the right number of parentheses? Can't tell for sure without seeing your full formula. Best would be to update your question with latest formula and screenshot of the error message